# My code won't work, because of operators:PYTHON

Tags: python

I am making a text to binary translator and needed to make my x go up by increments of one. But when I do this it wont let me. Here is the part python does not like,

```
if beep == 1:
    if x < length:
        x + 1 = x
```

Comment: You're going to get lots of downvotes because this question means you haven't learned the basics of the language. SO is not a replacement for reading a textbook or tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

`x + 1 = x` is an invalid expression in python (invalid in almost all other programming languages).

`x = x + 1` will be a valid increment.

You need to see first how [Assignment Operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/assignment_operators_example.htm) works.

> Assigns values from right side operands to left side operand.

Answer (score 1):

When updating variables, the variable by itself needs to be on the left of the assignment operator. So instead of `x + 1 = x`, use `x = x + 1` or simply `x += 1`

Answer (score 0):

you cant do operations in left hand side. so `x + 1 = x` is invalid in python.

You can do this by: `x = x + 1` or `x += 1`